# GKE How many Persistent Disks could be attached to a single node?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to attach ~30 persistent disks to single k8s node (e.g. n1-standard-4)?

According to the documentation 2-4 core node can support up to 64 attached disks in Beta: [Link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#increased_persistent_disk_limits).

Is it supported by GKE? Is there any limit in GKE Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GKE has the same limitation as vanilla Kubernetes on GCP per se. The Kubernetes limits for the largest public cloud providers are documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-limits/#kubernetes-default-limits)

You can also change those limits using the `KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS` on the `kube-scheduler` (After restarting). Unfortunately, you won't be able to change this on GKE yet, because GKE doesn't give you access to the master(s) configuration yet.

Also documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-limits/#dynamic-volume-limits) is Dynamic Volume Limits introduced in Kubernetes 1.11 and currently in Beta.

I believe you self-answered your first question, the `n1-standard-4` VM has 4 vCPUs and per the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#increased_persistent_disk_limits) that you provided you can attach up to 64 disks. So yes, you should be able to attach 30 persistent disks, a PVC/PV in the GCE storage class maps to GCP VM disk.

Comment: Thank you! Bu I can google that info too, what about exact answer for the first question? And your first link pointing to something different.

Comment: Thx. Updated the link, I believe you self-answered your first questions, yes you should be able to attach 30 PVCs, a PVC in the GCE storage class maps to GCP VM disk.

Comment: The answer from google support: "I'll also raise a case on our product specialist if this feature will be available  on GKE since changing the value of KUBE_MAX_PD_VOLS in GKE is not possible."

Comment: Oh yeah. Thanks for pointing it out. Yes GKE doesn't give you direct access to the master(s) configuration. Updated the answer.